# Java - splitting a delimited file into smaller parts based on first item in each line

Tags: java, csv, split

I have a pipe-delimited file that looks something like the following:

```
H||||||
S||||||
S||||||
H||||||
S||||||
H||||||
S||||||
S||||||
```

I'm trying to split it into smaller parts where a line beginning with `H` will indicate the start of a part, so something link the following:

```
H||||||
S||||||
S||||||

H||||||
S||||||

H||||||
S||||||
S||||||
```

I so far have the following which will split the file up and check the first item in each line, but I'm a little unsure as to how I would achieve the next bit where the each part could be passed on (to another method for example) for processing.

```
private static String splitFile(String fileString) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileString.getBytes());

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineArray = line.split("\\|");

        if (lineArray[0].equals("H")) {
            //get rest of this part of the file and forward for processing
        }
    }

    br.close();

    return null;
}
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file completely then split the whole string using regex pattern with [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
           (?=\nH)
   new line----^^-------Followed by H
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/xI2tG1/2)

Sample code:

```
String[] array = wholeString.split("(?=\nH)");
```

---

Complete sample code:

```
StringBuilder wholeString=new StringBuilder();
String line=null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    wholeString.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
}

String[] array = wholeString.toString().split("(?=\nH)");
```

---

Note: `System.lineSeparator()`

- On UNIX systems, it returns `"\n"`
- On Microsoft Windows systems it returns `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user3218114. I've given this a go and it gets me very close to what I'm trying to achieve. The only issue is that when I print each item in the array `array`, all items other than that at position 0 seem to have a blank line before the `H` line. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: use `wholeString.replaceAll("(\r?\n){2,}","")` to replace blank lines. Add more sample input in your original post for clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this block

```
String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineArray = line.split("\\|");

        if (lineArray[0].equals("H")) {
            //get rest of this part of the file and forward for processing
        }
    }
```

with

```
ArrayList lines= new ArrayList();              // list that holds all lines
String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineArray = line.split("\\|");

        if (lineArray[0].equals("H")) {
            lines.add("\n");                    // add blank line
        }

         lines.add(line);                       // add each line in list
    }

// Here TODO - pass arraylist for further processing.
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
private static String splitFile(String fileString) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new StringReader(fileString));
    String line=null;
    StringBuffer cache=null;
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        if(line.startsWith("H"))
        {
            // new section
            if(cache!=null)
            {
                // process previous block
                String content=cache.toString();
                // do your further processing with the content
                System.out.println(content);
            }
            cache=new StringBuffer(line);
        } else
            cache.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    return null;
}
```

Some extra remarks:

- StringReader converts a String to a Reader without going through a ByteArray which can can give encoding issues.
- I don't know why you split your line if you just need the first character to check.
- The `cache!=null` condition will only be false at the beginning of the file.